# Building goldfish kernel: "goldfish_armv7_defconfig" not found at "arch/x86/configs"

Tags: android, build, android-emulator, kernel, arm

I'm facing a strange problem (at least, to me) and I hope someone knows how to solve it!

I'm trying to build android goldfish kernel 2.6.29 on ubuntu 13.04 (actually xubuntu 13.04), to run on the emulator. So, I took these steps:

**1 - Download the goldfish kernel:**
`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish`
`git checkout -t origin/android-goldfish-2.6.29 -b goldfish`

**2 - Download the prebuilt toolchain to compile for arm architecture:**
`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilt`

**3 - Export environment variables to compile for arm achitecture:**
`export ARCH=arm`
`export SUBARCH=arm`
`export PATH={prebuilt_folder_dir}/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin:$PATH`
`export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-`

At this point I should be able to build the configuration file "goldfish_armv7_defconfig".

But, when I do:
`make goldfish_armv7_defconfig`

I get an error saying that the file "goldfish_armv7_defconfig" is not found at "arch/x86/configs". Why is it pointing to **arch/x86** instead of **arch/arm**?

If I run:
`make goldfish_defconfig`

I'll get the image **arch/x86/boot/bzImage** and this does not run on the emulator. I want the image **arch/arm/boot/zImage**.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE arguments via make:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- goldfish_armv7_defconfig
```

Comment: It Worked! Thanks Christophe.

But, what's the difference between define ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE as environment variables and define as arguments in make? Shouldn't be the same?

Comment: Make variables and environment variables are not the same. If you look at the Makefile, you will see that it defines the SUBARCH, ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE variables. To override their value, you have to pass these variables as argument to make.